# Class for DB connection, how to use

Tags: php, class

I'm playing around with classes in php and just can't find the right way to do so.

I have the following class:

```
class db_connection {
    private $dbc;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dbc = new mysqli(HOST_ONE, USER_ONE, PASS_ONE, DB_ONE) or die ($this->dbc->error);

    }

    public function getDbc()
    {
        return $this->dbc;
    }

}
```

and try to run it like this:

```
$db = new db_connection();
$db->getDbc();

// TESTQUERY
$abfrage = "SELECT * FROM databases";
$result = $db->query($abfrage);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['id'];
}
```

HOST_ONE and so on are set, I don't get any error messages though I have `error_reporting( E_ALL );` enabled

I tried it in many different ways, but none of them is working...

Can someone push me in the right direction on how to use this simple class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use it like:

```
$db_con = new db_connection();
$db = $db_con->getDbc();
```

The function getDbc() returns the object you need. As so you have to send it to $db variable, to get it. Executing the method does not attribute its value to "self"($db_con) but returns a value.

Comment: Explain why it should be so

Answer (score 1):

You should use code like this:

```
$dbClass = new db_connection();
$db = $dbClass->getDbc();
$db->query("SELECT * FROM databases");
```

`$dbClass = new db_connection();` creates connection and returns `db_connection` class instance to `$dbClass`. Now that you have connected to database, use `$db = $dbClass->getDbc();` to get connection object itself and do any database related actions with it.